# apt-get update show: CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

`sudo apt-get update`

W: Failed to fetch https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/dists/docker/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

`openssl s_client -connect get.docker.com:443 -tls1 -debug` => http://paste.ubuntu.com/10687412

my machine is Ubuntu 14.10

any ideas?

Comment: Solved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319538/issue-with-my-ca-certificates-crt

Answer (score -2):

Scratched my head for couple of days, eventually this worked

```
USER root
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

RUN apt-get update

Comment: Yes, that would work, because you delete any additional repositories.