# Issue with my ca-certificates.crt

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ca

(I am on Ubuntu 14.10. uname -r => 3.16.0-31-generic)

apt-get update

```
Failed to fetch https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/dists/docker/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none.
```

git clone https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat.git

```
I can't clone anything - fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none.
```

docker run hello-world

```
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

ls /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -l

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1964 Mar 26 18:19 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

All of my ca certificates were missing from /usr/share/ca-certificates/*
re-installing the package put them back

If they are missing from that location, doing a force reloading will show the 0 of 0:

update-ca-certificates -f

```
Clearing symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs...done.  
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
```

apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

```
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20141019ubuntu0.14.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.14.10.1) over (20141019ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
173 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

Answer (score 10):

Another cause might be your server time: check whether your server time is correct by running `date`. If it isn't, run `sudo ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com`. An incorrect server time can invalidate ssl certificates

In my case, I restored a server snapshot. As a result, the server time was still set to snapshot-time. A reboot would probably solve this issue as well, as ubuntu tries to update the time on boot.

Comment: This was my problem, with certs. I spent hours looking at all sorts of solutions before discovering that the problem was the server clock being set way into the future.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! This was my problem.